# actually recognizing hexadecimal but noto converting in hex calculator with flex and bison

Tags: hex, calculator, bison, flex-lexer

I have a problem with a calculator in flex and bison
in this code

```
0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+ {yylval=strtol(yytext,0 ,16);return HEX;}
```

it actually recognize hexadecimal values,and do the math operations  but when i want to print the result it print it in decimal.

so i think its a problem wiht this part:

```
/*main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int tok;
while(tok = yylex()) {
printf("%d", tok);
if(tok == NUMBER) printf(" = %d\n", yylval);
else 
if(tok == HEX) 
printf(" = %x\n", yylval);
else
printf("\n");
}
}*/
```

Comment: Why is your code inside a comment? Also please post an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where is the part where you "do math operations"? If you in comment main` in the code you included, does it work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

`strtol` used in the way you use it, converts ASCII<sup>1</sup> hex into binary integer form.  As an `int` or `long` you can then do operations on it (adding, subtracting, multiplying, etc), which you can't do on numbers in ASCII (string) form.  To actually display a number, you need to convert it back into ASCII, which is what `printf` does.  With the `%d` conversion it converts to ASCII decimal -- if you want ASCII hex, use `%x`

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Strictly speaking it might be any character set, not necessarily ASCII, but pretty much all C compilers use ASCII or some extension of it for their basic character set</sub>